# How to extract maximal value from a group of variables in a data frame

Tags: r

I am having problems with function `max()` in the extraction of maximal value from a group of variables. The data.frame is the next and all variables are numeric:

```
setosa  versicolor  virginica
    0   0.96969697  0.03030303
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795
    0   0.96969697  0.03030303
    1   0.00000000  0.00000000
    1   0.00000000  0.00000000
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795
```

When I apply `max()` function to this data frame and I try to save it in a new variable it happens:

`DF$max=max(DF$setosa,DF$versicolor,DF$virginica)`

```
setosa  versicolor  virginica   max
    0   0.96969697  0.03030303  1
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795  1
    0   0.96969697  0.03030303  1
    1   0.00000000  0.00000000  1
    1   0.00000000  0.00000000  1
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795  1
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795  1
    0   0.05128205  0.94871795  1
```

It seems `max()` function round the maximal value. I can't find my mistake, can you help me what is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You statement gets the value for the maximum of all elements. Try to use `apply`:

```
R > dat$max <-  apply(dat, 1, max)
R > dat
  setosa versicolor  virginica      max
1      0 0.96969697 0.03030303 0.969697
2      0 0.05128205 0.94871795 0.948718
3      0 0.96969697 0.03030303 0.969697
4      1 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.000000
5      1 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.000000
6      0 0.05128205 0.94871795 0.948718
7      0 0.05128205 0.94871795 0.948718
8      0 0.05128205 0.94871795 0.948718
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten `apply()`. @liuminzhao

Comment: Don't use `apply` on data.frame -- it will coerce to a matrix and thus be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks @mnel. Duck, please be aware of mnel's advice on inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pmax` for that

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15), ncol = 3))



cbind(dat,
      max = pmax(dat$X1, dat$X2, dat$X3)
)

##         X1        X2       X3     max
## 1  0.42646  0.688640 -0.69471 0.68864
## 2 -0.29507  0.553918 -0.20792 0.55392
## 3  0.89513 -0.061912 -1.26540 0.89513
## 4  0.87813 -0.305963  2.16896 2.16896
## 5  0.82158 -0.380471  1.20796 1.20796
```

Comment: `do.call(pmax, data[c('X1','X2','X3'])` provides an alternative approach (perhaps easier to extend)

Answer (score 1):

`max` returns a single value that is the maximum of *all* the arguments submitted to it. So the max value across all three columns in your data is 1 which is what `max returns:

```
max(df$setosa,df$versicolor,df$virginica)
[1] 1
```

You then assign it to a new column in your data.frame, and due to the way R is designed recycling on the assignment occurs such that the value returned from max is reused until the size of the vector it is being assigned to is full, in this case, the number of rows in your data frame.

If you want the max of each column, do

```
apply( df , 2 , max )
   setosa versicolor  virginica 
 1.000000   0.969697   0.948718
```

Which applies the `max` function to each column and returns the result. If you want to know which row contains the `max` value for each column use `which.max` like so

```
apply( df , 2 , which.max )
 setosa versicolor  virginica 
     4          1          2
```

And if you want the `max` across the values by row, set the MARGIN argument to `apply` to be 1 (here the MARGIN argument is set using positional matching rather than being named explicitly):

```
df$max <- apply( df , 1 , max )
```